# Incompatible pointer type in function call - C

Tags: c, pointers, incompatibility

I have a program below

```
#include<stdio.h>

void int_frac(double a, long *int_part,double *frac_part)
{
  *int_part = (long int)(a);
  *frac_part = a - *int_part;
}
int main()
{
  long int* ip;
  double* fp;
  double i = 1.2345467;

  int_frac(i,&ip,&fp);
  printf("%f = %ld + %f",i,*ip,*fp);
  return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc compiler.
This program gives an error:

> expected long int* but argument is of type long int**
>
> and
>
> expected double* but argument is of type double**

Why this error comes up.

Comment: [modf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/modf)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why are you providing links to http://linux.die.net/ which is hopelessly out of date, and also specific to Linux. Here is a much better link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/modf

Comment: Nor does it mean that linux limited and  nor does old information. It is like have well-written.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Wrong. It's Linux documentation, that may have overlap, and is out of date. Linux docs are found at kernel.org.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please tell me if there is an error in the **content**.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It's just irrelevant to the question. The question is tagged C. There is no mention of POSIX. Do you want to learn or not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It does not mean POSIX only , also be written as c99.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so you think linux.die is the best documentation source for the C standard library? If so, I give up.

Comment: I do not think be the best, but as being well organized.

Comment: &BLUEPIXY, I knew about modf already. I was just learning passing pointer variables to a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you are passing `long int**` where it expects `long int*`. And that you are passing `double**` where it expects `double*`.

The compiler is correct. You declared `ip` to be `long int*` and then passed `&ip` which has type `long int**`. You made the same mistake with `fp`.

What you have done is declare two pointers, `ip` and `fp`, but not initialized the pointers. The fundamental problem is that you have declared pointers but have not allocated any variables. If `int_frac` is to be able to write to variables, those variables must be allocated somewhere. So, what you need to do is declare two values, and pass the addresses of those values to `int_frac`.

Your code should be:

```
int main()
{
    long int ip; // allocates a variable
    double fp; // as does this
    double i = 1.2345467;

    int_frac(i,&ip,&fp); // pass the addresses of ip and fp
    printf("%f = %ld + %f",i,ip,fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error which you received is the answer in my opinion as you are passing `long int**` when it expects `long int*` You need to declare `ip` as `long int ip` like this:

```
int main()
{
    long int ip;
    double fp;
    double i = 1.2345467;

    int_frac(i,&ip,&fp);
    printf("%f = %ld + %f",i,ip,fp);
    return 0;
}
```